# Fancy indexing for numpy arrary

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sample `len(valid_frame_id_ls)` frame from data by fancy indexing for numpy arrary. But I received an error message when i run code1. I don't know why the shape of `data[n, :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]` is not equal to  the shape of `new_data[n, :, :len(valid_frame_id_ls), :, :]`.Can anyone help me solve this bug. help...

I modify my code and write in code2 block. I did't receive any error message when i run code2. I don't know why code2 is correct.

## code1:

```
    data = np.random.random((2, 3, 50, 25, 1))
    N, C, T, V, M = data.shape
    new_data = np.zeros((N, C, T, V, M))
    valid_frame_id_ls = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for n in range(N):
        new_data[n, :, :len(valid_frame_id_ls), :, :] = data[n, :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]
```

```
# code1 error message:
    new_data[n, :, :len(valid_frame_id_ls), :, :] = data[n, :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,3,25,1) into shape (3,5,25,1)
```

## code2:

```
    data = np.random.random((2, 3, 50, 25, 1))
    N, C, T, V, M = data.shape
    new_data = np.zeros((N, C, T, V, M))
    valid_frame_id_ls = [2, 3, 4, 5, 11]
    for n in range(N):
        new_data[n][:, :len(valid_frame_id_ls), :, :] = data[n][ :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]
```

Comment: The RHS is a mix of `basic` and `advanced` indexing, a documented issue.  Your code2 is the right way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

As described in this section of the docs, putting a slice in the middle of 'advanced' indexing results in an unexpected rearrangement of dimensions.  Your size 5 dimension has been placed first, and the other dimensions after.

This has come up occasionally on SO as well. With a scalar `n` this really shouldn't be happening, but apparently the issue occurs deep in the indexing, and isn't easily corrected.

```
data[n][ :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]
```

breaks up the indexing, so the first ':' is no longer in the middle.

Another fix is to replace the slice with an equivalent array.  Now both sides will have the same dimensions.

```
new_data[n, :, np.arange(len(valid_frame_id_ls)), :, :] = data[n, :, valid_frame_id_ls, :, :]
```

Though in this case I don't think you need to iterate on `N` at all:

```
new_data[:,:,:len(valid_frame_id_ls),:,:] = data[:,:, valid_frame_id_ls, :,:]
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I get it. And the docs  is so helpful.